# Understanding how well Gradient Descent can "work" on Non-Convex Functions

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent, non-convex-optimization

**I am interested in understanding how well the Gradient Descent algorithm can "work" (e.g. convergence) on Non-Convex (and Noisy) Functions.**

As we know, there has been a lot of work and research done to demonstrate that the Gradient Descent Algorithm can converge on (deterministic) differentiable and Lipschitz Continuous functions :

[image]

However, I am interested in learning about to what extent convergence of Gradient Descent Based Algorithms (e.g. Stochastic Gradient Descent) has been studied for (non-deterministic) Non-Convex Functions (**Note**: In the field of Machine Learning, the functions being optimized are almost always Non-Convex and Non-Deterministic).

I have been trying to read about this topic over the past few weeks, but the level of math required to understand some of these results goes far beyond my ability to understand. For instance, below are some of the publications that I consulted:

**1)**  **"Stochastic Gradient Descent for Nonconvex Learning without Bounded Gradient Assumptions" (Lei et al., 2019)**

In this paper, the authors comment that:

- *Stochastic Gradient Descent is being heavily used on Non-Convex Functions, but the theoretical behavior of Stochastic Gradient Descent on Non-Convex Functions is not fully understood (currently only understood for Convex Functions).*
- *Currently, Stochastic Gradient Descent requires imposing a nontrivial assumption on the uniform boundedness of gradients.*
- *The authors establish a  theoretical foundation for Stochastic Gradient Descent for
  Non-Convex Functions where the boundedness assumption can be removed without affecting convergence rates.*
- *The authors establish sufficient conditions for almost sure convergence
  as well as optimal convergence rates for Stochastic Gradient Descent applied to Non-Convex Functions.*

**2) "Stochastic Gradient Descent on Nonconvex Functions with General Noise Models" (Patel et al 2021)**

In this paper, the authors comment that:

- *Although recent advancements in Stochastic Gradient Descent have been noteworthy, these advancements have nonetheless imposed certain restrictions (e.g., Convexity, Global Lipschitz Continuity etc.) on the functions being optimized.*
- *The authors prove that for general class of Non-Convex Functions, Stochastic Gradient Descent iterates either diverge to infinity or converge to a stationary point with probability one.*
- *The authors make further restrictions and prove that regardless of whether the iterates diverge or remain finite — the norm of the gradient function evaluated at Stochastic Gradient Descent's iterates converges to zero with probability one and in expectation; thus broadening the scope of functions to which Stochastic Gradient Descent can be applied to
  while maintaining rigorous guarantees of its global behavior.*

**My Question:** **Based on some of these publications, have we truly been able to demonstrate that (Stochastic) Gradient Descent has the potential to display similar global convergence properties on Non-Convex Functions, to the same extent at which it had previously displayed only on Convex Functions?**

Or have I completely misunderstood the results from this publications, and the conditions (and class of functions) in which the respective authors explored and demonstrated the convergence behavior of Stochastic Gradient Descent is far less "generous" compared to those pertaining to Convex Functions - and these conditions are also less likely to manifest themselves in real-world applications : And thus **we still have reasons to believe that (Stochastic) Gradient Descent has more difficulties converging on Non-Convex Functions compared to Convex Functions?**

Can someone please comment on this?

Thanks!

**References:**

- https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.00908
- https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.00423.pdf

Comment: Convergence to local minimum could be expected (with probability 1) for SGD in any smooth problem, If I would make a hypothesis. That's a type of notion that everyone on optimization has, but hardly someone proves it, because of the deep math required to solve that question. In optimization, we are needing someone to be "the one" to prove all the intuitions in an uniformized way behind this algorithm. I would say that, as soon that one make it, he would be praised in the optimization community for sure.

Comment: *Nothing* will ever have "global convergence properties" on non-convex functions. Just think of how pathological non-convex functions can be. Convexity is a property that puts some constraints on global behavior, if you want convergence you need to replace it with some other such property, not lack of one. What people do in non-convex optimization is look for relaxing convexity to something that still works *and* holds in their applications.

Comment: Conifold, for gradient descent to converge, it's needed nothing more than continuously  twice  differentiability. I think the article “Gradient Descent Converges to Minimizers” would be helpful for you. Nothing seems to be known for the SGD yet.

Comment: @R.W.Prado Convergence to a local minimizer is not a "global convergence property". And continuous twice differentiability in a neighborhood of a local minimizer is not much less than convexity there. There are much weaker properties in non-smooth optimization that one can still make do with, but all of that is a far cry from general non-convex functions.